# Display some images with mysql_fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have to create some php pages that allow you to insert and display some random images (saved as blob in my mysql DB).
Well, when i try it it give to me that error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource.
And here my page:

```
 $n="SELECT COUNT('id_product')
 FROM 'products'";
$value=mysql_query($n);

do
{
 $selectionASC='SELECT id_product 
        FROM products 
        ORDER BY id_product ASC
        LIMIT 1';
 $selectionDESC='SELECT id_product 
         FROM products 
         ORDER BY id_product DESC
         LIMIT 1';
  $ASC=mysql_query($selectionASC)
    or die ('Impossible execute the query <br />').mysql_error();
  $DESC=mysql_query($selectionDESC)
    or die ('Impossible execute the query <br />').mysql_error();

  //____________________________________________________________________
  $rand_n=rand(($ASC-1),($DESC+1));

  //____________________________________________________________________
  $selected='SELECT id_product,name, price, img
         FROM products
         WHERE id_product='.$rand_n;
  //____________________________________________________________________
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($selected))
        {
            echo "Product'id: &nbsp"; echo $row[0];
            echo '<br />';
            echo "Name: &nbsp"; echo $row[1];
            echo '<br />';
            echo "Price:: &nbsp"; echo $row[2];
            echo '<br />';
            echo "Immage: <img src='images/".$row['img']."' alt='Image'>";;
            echo '<hr> <br />';

            $value--;
        }
}
while ($value==0)
```

could someone be so kind to tell me where am I wrong? Thanks and sorry for my poor english!

EDIT:

```
$allowedExts=array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
   $temp=explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension=end($temp);

if(isset($_FILES['file']['name']))
{
    if(!empty($_FILES['file']['name']))
    {
        $directory='\www\v1.2\loaded';
        $uploadfile = $directory . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

        if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
             || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
             || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
             || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
             || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
             || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
             && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
             && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
        {
                if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
                {
                 echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
                }
                else
                {
                //$nameImage=$_FILES(["file"]["name"]);
                $typeImage=$_FILES["file"]["type"];
                $sizeImage=$_FILES["file"]["size"];

                    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
                     {
                          echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
                     }
                    else
                    {
                          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
                          {
                              $insert="INSERT INTO 'img'
                               VALUES ('','$uploadfile','$typeImage','$sizeImage')";
                              echo "File's extension valid, upload executed";
                          }
                          else
                          {
                           echo "Upload failed: ceck the size and the extension";
                          }
                        }
                }
        }
        else
        {
        echo "Invalid file";
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't pass `img` in array. you have to pass index number because you have used `mysql_fetch_array`
so, replace this line from code,

```
  echo "Immage: <img src='images/".$row['img']."' alt='Image'>";;
```

to

```
echo "Immage: <img src='images/".$row['3']."' alt='Image'>";
```

**Here i guess img url is store on 3rd index. please must check image index and replace the value of 3**

================================================================================

Better way to use `mysql_fetch_assoc`. In that case you don't require  to find index of column from database

simply replace while loop from your code. **it will Definitely work**

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($selected))
        {
            echo "Product'id: &nbsp"; echo $row['id_product'];
            echo '<br />';
            echo "Name: &nbsp"; echo $row['name'];
            echo '<br />';
            echo "Price:: &nbsp"; echo $row['price'];
            echo '<br />';
            echo "Immage: <img src='images/".$row['img']."' alt='Image'>";
            echo '<hr> <br />';

            $value--;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, it was usefull! But, in the place off the image, it stamp the "source code". Any suggest?

Comment: what do you mean ? plz explain one again

Comment: When i run the page on my server the page works and show me everything except the image. In the place of it appear some chars, not the binary code, but instead something like this: @aCf#124sf and so on.

Comment: why u are storing binary code ? can't u store image path only ?

Comment: Honestly? Actually i don't know how do it! It's the first time that i have to manage this kind of data.

Comment: for example : create one folder with name of "upload" in your directory. and upload images in that folder using "move_uploaded_file" function. and insert simple "path of that directory + image name" in your database.  [PHP FILE UPLOAD](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp). Make sure path is right. for local testing create upload folder on same directory. so whenever execute insert query simply write path name + image name

Comment: get image path using $path = "upload/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
and insert this path in database. ** Don't insert image directly ** on database. it's really a badly for developer..

Comment: Ok, with some more work i figured out how make it works!
Thanks for the attention!

Answer (score 0):

As per your code I see that you miss the statement of

$selected = mysql_query($selected);

above the line of

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($selected)){
........
}

Check this should help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is`$rand_n=rand(($ASC-1),($DESC+1));`, `$ASC and $DESC` are resource not integers, instead you should probably use 
`$ASC = mysql_num_rows($ASC);
  $DESC = mysql_num_rows($DESC);`
then you can use `$rand_n=rand(($ASC-1),($DESC+1));`

```
 $selected='SELECT id_product,name, price, img
     FROM products
     WHERE id_product='.$rand_n;
 $selected = mysql_query($selected);

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($selected))
    {
        echo "Product'id: &nbsp"; echo $row['id_product'];
        echo '<br />';
        echo "Name: &nbsp"; echo $row['name'];
        echo '<br />';
        echo "Price:: &nbsp"; echo $row['price'];
        echo '<br />';
        echo "Immage: <img src='images/".$row['img']."' alt='Image'>";
        echo '<hr> <br />';

        $value--;
    }
```